# Excel Power Map - How to highlight entire country

Tags: excel, dictionary

Using Power Map for Excel 2013, I am trying to figure out how to highlight an entire country. Currently, when I have a Country name, it simply places a dot in the middle of that country. I want to highlight the entire country.

Does anyone perhaps know how to accomplish this?
An example of what I am trying to achieve can be seen 2m55s  into this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFEq3m2RABQ&list=WL&index=5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the Layer Pane, click the second tab called Field List.

At the bottom, you will see a few charts above the word "VALUE".

Click the chart on the far right, "change the visualization to region."